# Select the second word

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<span>Lies Hendriks</span>
```

How can I select the second word with CSS. I can not change the HTML of this document.
I want give "Hendriks" another style. Or can I do it with JavaScript?

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot change the html of that page?

Comment: You can't change how the page is generated, or you can't change the HTML structure with JavaScript afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to split up into seperate entities to apply different styles to each word.

```
<span style="style1">Lies</span><span style="style2">Hendriks</span>
```

There is no way to selectively apply styles to a single word using JS or CSS without changing the HTML itself.

Comment: Really? You can't do it with JS and 3 people upvoted this? I would understand someone saying that this is a questionable practice or that it requires control over JS injection/loading on the specific page,  but **can't**?

Comment: Sorry, @ChrisBint, but that is still incorrect. Depending on HTML file organization - you can do it with JS without changing one HTML element. For example if the HTML file includes your module, or loads JS dynamically and you have access to the JS code. With CSS, this is simply not something you can not do, period.

Comment: @ZenMaster But _the js_ is changing the HTML. That's the point @ChrisBint is trying to make `

Comment: @Eric there is a **big** difference between changing the HTML **file**  and modifying the DOM after the HTML content is rendered. The latter is an extremely accepted technique. So, I guess, it's a matter of semantics - what Chris means when he says 'HTML' - the original HTML source or the parsed and rendered DOM that corresponds to that HTML source.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do with CSS, but if you know your structure (for instance, that it's always the second word you need to style differently) you can do it with JavaScript (assuming that you can inject your JS into the page, of course).

This is an example that may be a bit convoluted, but if your HTML has:

```
<span>Lies Hendriks</span>
```

then you can do it like so (upon your DOM loading event):

```
 var span1 = document.getElementById('span1');
 span1.innerHTML = span1.innerHTML.replace(/(\s+)(.*)/, '$1<span class="red">$2</span>');
```

assuming you have

```
.red
{
    color: red;
}
```

in your CSS

The above code allows me to make everything after the first word red. That should give you an idea how to do that, depending on your structure.

Comment: Nice. It would be a good practice for the downvoter to leave a comment.